# Using php variables in Sql

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

i have a form that is used to set a search term to a php variable VIA _GET so for example if the user typed cat the url would say ?search=cat

Here is the PHP variable that will be used in the SQL query

```
$search = 'CustomerAccountName LIKE &#39;%'  . $_GET['search'] . '%&#39;';
```

When echoed this produces CustomerAccountName LIKE '%cat%' which is valid and works when using the query editor however when i try to place the $search variable in to the query in php i get this error

```
Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect
 syntax near '&amp;'., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Bobby tables is salivating by just looking at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use plain single quotes.

```
$search = "CustomerAccountName LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%';";
```

But don't build your query like this. [Sanitize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) it before to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = "CustomerAccountName LIKE '%"  . $_GET['search'] . "%' ";
```